# Why does bottom table cell that has centered-text get cut off when displayed as PDF in iOS?

Tags: html, ios, css, swift, pdf

**Question**

I have an iOS app that takes an html file, turns it into a PDF, and displays it to a WebKit web view. I have a weird problem where the bottom table cell gets cut off when I display to PDF. The weird thing is that the bottom table is only cut off when the text is centered. If it is left-aligned, everything works fine. Why does this happen?

Please note that I am not looking for a work around solution. Rather, I am seeking to understand why this happens. Is this a bug in iOS? Or did I miss something?

**Overview**

In the image below, there are two tables `<table>`. One table is large, has a reddish (coral) background, and has a height of 505px. The other table is below the first with a white background (height is not set). Both have some text. The text is centered for both tables.

The navbar title shows the details of the current view. For example, as shown in the image below, a title of **PDF Landscape 505** means that the view shows a PDF in landscape dimensions with a main table height of 505px.

[image]

**The Problem**

The problem arises when I increase the height by 10px. In the image below, the main table height is 515px and the lower table is now cut off.

[image]

Take the exact same html and css code and change only the text-alignment to be left-aligned. Now the lower table is not cut off anymore. I also changed the background color to green for distinction. Green means that text is left-aligned. Red means that text is centered.

[image]

The following image shows a main-table height of 745px and still the lower table is not cut off because it is left-aligned.

[image]

**Code**

Below is the html code used for this test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>#COLOR#</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
  table, th, td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 3px solid black;
    text-align: #ALIGN#;
  }
  table.main-table {
    width: 1012px;
    height: #HEIGHT#px;
    background-color: #COLOR#;
  }
  table.bottom-table {
    width: 1012px;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table class="main-table">
    <tr><td>Hello World.</td></tr>
  </table>
  <table class="bottom-table">
    <tr><td>This text gets cut off when centered. It does *not* get cut when left-aligned.</td></tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

In `MyViewController`, the `getHTML()` function pulls the html source from `sample.html`. The function then replaces `#ALIGN#`, `#COLOR#`, and `#HEIGHT#` with their respective values.

```
func getHTML() -> String? {
    let htmlPath: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: htmlResource, ofType: "html")
    guard let path = htmlPath else { return nil }
    do {
        // Load the HTML template code into a String variable.
        var html = try String(contentsOfFile: path)
        html = html.replacingOccurrences(of: "#HEIGHT#", with: tableHeight.description)
        html = html.replacingOccurrences(of: "#COLOR#", with: colorState.rawValue)
        html = html.replacingOccurrences(of: "#ALIGN#", with: alignState.rawValue)
        return html
    } catch {
        print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return nil
}
```

The PDFBuilder class handles the PDF creation with one function:

```
static func exportHTMLToPDF(html: String, frame: CGRect) -> Data {
    // Set a printable frame and inset                
    let pageFrame = frame
    let insetRect = pageFrame.insetBy(dx: 10.0, dy: 10.0)

    // Create a UIPrintPageRenderer and set the paperRect and printableRect using above values.
    let pageRenderer = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    pageRenderer.setValue(pageFrame, forKey: "paperRect")
    pageRenderer.setValue(insetRect, forKey: "printableRect")

    // Create a printFormatter and pass the HTML code as a string.
    let printFormatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: html)

    // Add the printFormatter to the pageRenderer
    pageRenderer.addPrintFormatter(printFormatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)

    // This data var is where the PDF will be stored once created.
    let data = NSMutableData()

    // This is where the PDF gets drawn.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, pageFrame, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
    pageRenderer.drawPage(at: 0, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())
    print("bounds: " + UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds().debugDescription)        
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    return data as Data
}
```

This project is also on Github:
 https://github.com/starkindustries/PrintPDFTest

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken**

1. Dimensions: I tried playing around with the size of the PDF dimensions. This did not make a difference in the result.
2. Columns: I tried using multiple columns instead of just one. Same problem; no difference.
3. Tables: I tried using just one table instead of two. With one table and two cells, the bottom cell still gets cut off when text is centered; bottom cell does not get cut when text is left-aligned.
4. iPhones: I tried simulating on different iPhone devices (iPhone 6s, iPhone 8, iPad Pro). Same issue.
5. Div: If you use a div instead of a second table, the problem is magically fixed. But why does a div work and not a table?

**App Notes**

The top toolbar has two buttons: **green** and **red**. Green makes the text left-aligned. Red makes the text centered.

[image]

The bottom toolbar has five buttons: **rewind**, **html**, **portrait**, **landscape**, and **fast forward**. The **rewind** button reduces the main table's height by 10px. **Fast forward** increases the height by 10px. The **html** button shows the html view. **Portrait** and **landscape** show PDF's in their respective orientations.

[image]

Comment: Is there any other HTML or CSS that could be important to the question? Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/6udog328/

Comment: No, there is no other HTML/CSS code other than what I posted. The full source is in the github link if you would like to verify or tinker. The problem occurs in the iOS app specifically when printing to PDF. There is no problem when it displays as html. Therefore, the jsfiddle does not replicate the conditions.

Comment: Have you tried setting an explicit height in your bottom table?

Comment: @KenBoreham Yes, same issue occurs.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. If nobody figures anything out before the bounty expires, then I would report it [*here*](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/).

Comment: Try and take your web page and pass it though cutePDF writer / or another pdf writer and see if the same behavior happends. Also look into if your webpage is print friendly, for inspiration http://www.creativebloq.com/responsive-web-design/make-your-website-printable-css-3132929

Comment: Could you possibly add `table-layout: fixed` to your css (to both the tables) and let us know if the problem persists?

Comment: Hi @DeadLock. I just tried your suggestion. The problem still persists.

Comment: Taking a shot in the dark here - may be apply `text-align: center` only to the `table td` exclusively, rather than `table,th,td`?

Comment: Also note that most HTML-to-PDF converters (eg: dompdf for php) have trouble generating PDFs for HTML that extensively uses tables (nested tables mostly, which I know isn't specifically the case here). This would explain the reason that the problem gets fixed when you replace the table with div instead.

Comment: @DeadLock, nice suggestion to narrow it down further, but no luck. I tried removing align from `table,th, td` and used `td { text-align: #ALIGN#; }`. Same issue occurs.

Comment: @Coder256, I submitted a bug report to Apple per your suggestion. The problem ID is 36071788. I'll update if/when Apple responds. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @ZionPerez Thanks, any chance you could post it on OpenRadar?

Comment: @Coder256, no problem. Here is the link: [rdar://36071788](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5036527407071232)

Answer (score 1):

I had many troubles with PDF rendering in order to keep the exact same aspect and size then my HTML file once transformed (mostly because of resolution translation problems).

The best and simpliest workaround that I found is to encapsulate the content in a container that exactly fit the height of the document.
You can use the media query to apply your css code only on the print result if you want to display your source html file.

```css
table, th, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

table.main-table {
  width: 1012px;
  height: 515px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

table.bottom-table {
  width: 1012px;
}

@media print {
  .main-container{
    height:1100px;/* adjust the height to fit your PDF document*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <table class="main-table">
    <tr><td>Hello World.</td></tr>
  </table>
  <table class="bottom-table">
    <tr><td>This text gets cut off when centered. It does *not* get cut when left-aligned.</td></tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Note that the most efficient way to fix size in a PDF is using "cm" instead of "px" if your rendering tool permit it, in order to avoid interpolation

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it has been sometime since the question has been posted. But I got myself intrigued with this, and was trying to figure out why this could be happening.

I also tried testing a variety of combinations to check this out. But it looks like no native iOS code could be of any help. But, assigning an **auto** height to the **bottom-table** seemed to do the job. Setting an explicit height did not work though.

```
table.bottom-table {
    width: 1012px;
    height: auto;
}
```

It looks like the PDF being rendered might have been having some issue in setting up the frame for the PDF, in the other case. I assume that you also know that the issue persisted in both Portrait and Landscape modes, when the height went above a certain limit.